# How to print a string literally in Python

Tags: python, ansi-escape

I need to print what a string in Python contains. I'm collecting data from a serial port and I need to know if it is sending CR or CRLF + other control codes that are not ASCII.

As an example say I had

```
s = "ttaassdd\n\rssleeroo"
```

then I would like to do is:

```
print s
```

Where it would show the `\n\r` rather than covert them into escape characters.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Python 2

```
>>> print repr(s)
'ttaassdd\n\rssleeroo'
```

Python 3

```
>>> print(repr(s))
'ttaassdd\n\rssleeroo'
```

Comment: `p = 'A\R\1\2'  print(repr(p))` gives 'A\\R\x01\x02'

Answer (score 2):

Saving your string as 'raw' string could also do the job.

(As in, by putting an 'r' in front of the string, like the example here)

```
    >>> s = r"ttaassdd\n\rssleeroo"
    >>> print s
    ttaassdd\n\rssleeroo
```

Comment: how to add 'r' when the string is in a variable?

Comment: The string is in a variable (```s```) as you can see above. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I meant, how can we add 'r' when the string we want to print is in a variable where the value is not assigned by us, but rather is given in the variable already. For example, the string variable is input to a function.

Comment: Right, in that case you should use ```repr``` as it's the actual function used to format the string anyway.

In your case:

```print(repr(some_str_input))```

Should do.