# How to print a string as it is written?

Tags: python, string, io

Let's say that I have a string like this: 'Hello \n this world is nice'. When calling the print function print('Hello \n this world is nice') the result would be such that a new line is introduced after 'Hello'.

If I wanted to print exactly

> 'Hello \n this world is nice'

so such that \n appears in the output of the print function as two characters), how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be using [[Python.Docs]: Built-in Functions - repr(object)](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html):

> ```py
> txt = "Hello \n this world is nice"
> >>> print(txt)
> Hello
>  this world is nice
> >>> print(repr(txt))
> 'Hello \n this world is nice'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the \ to print is as literal:

```
print('Hello \\n this world is nice')
```

Or add an r do interpret all in the string as literal (raw):

```
print(r'Hello \n this world is nice')
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here

[How to print a string literally in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903551/how-to-print-a-string-literally-in-python)

```
z = 'hello\n hello' 
print(repr(z))
>>> hello\n hello
```